# How can I use .findall to get certain characters from a line of text

Tags: python, regex

I have a line in a text file which is as follows:

```
0 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
```

The code I used for picking out the values `5.82020` and `7.61004` are as follows:

```
float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+",line)
```

If instead I wanted to pick out the words `1.H1'` and `2.H8`, what should I change in my code?

Also, there are multiple lines in my text file, I just picked one out as an example.

Comment: Do you want to pick those concrete values or is there any concrete format or rule?

Comment: If the format is always number.Hnumber you can go by: "\d\.H\d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big part of writing a nice regex is being able to describe and see the actual pattern.  In this case you would like:

```
{1.H1'}
```

and

```
{2.H8}
```

There isn't anything nice like value={blah} for you to grab so I like to start with the literal of what I'm going for:

```
thelist = re.findall("{2.H8}",line)
```

And then make it more generic to get the matches I really want (and escape the special characters), like this:

```
thelist = re.findall("\{\d\.H\d\}",line)
```

Cool.  Note you don't really need to escape the { or } but I usually do in case you end up with a number in there, then it would have a special meaning.  However we are missing the {1.H1'} so we need an optional ' like this:

```
thelist = re.findall("\{\d\.H\d'?\}",line)
```

Then if you find you are missing some, adjust as you see fit to make the pattern broader.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I wanted to add another special character, for example if my line included {1.H3'$}, then would I change it to 
re.findall("\{\d\.H\d'?\d$?\}",line)?

Comment: $ has a special meaning so it needs to be escaped.  The \d means a number.  So for  {1.H3'$} you would just want so to adjust like this: \{\d\.H\d'?\$?\}      The ? means that the previous character is optional.  So this regex means that there might be a $

Comment: There are all kinds of resources as to what does "this" regex mean?  Here is my favorite one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean  give that a look and you'll have a whole new pile of tools to write this stuff :)

Comment: I see, I'll definitely look through it, thanks again!